# ios8 cell constraints break when adding disclosure indicator

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, ios8

I have a problem with auto layout on IOS8, the simplest case I can recreate is a simple tableView.  I setup a static cell and then simply add a label.

My aim is to have the label largely fill the space, so I have three constraints on the label...

1. Centre it vertically within the superview (I think this is fine)
2. Set the label trailing margin to 30 (relative to superview)
3. Set the label leading margin to 30 (relative to superview)

It's all absolutely fine and works perfectly with no major problems or warning (it does warn about zero height, but I don't think that so much of an issue for this)

Now ... if I add a disclosure indicator it all falls apart. It still looks ok, but I get the following:

```
2014-10-30 15:51:46.358 ContraintIssue[25572:1586028] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
Try this: 
(1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
(2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
(Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, 
refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints) 
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fd3f3d23390 UITableViewCellContentView:0x7fd3f3d226f0.trailingMargin == UILabel:0x7fd3f3d227e0'Label'.trailing + 30>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fd3f3d235f0 UILabel:0x7fd3f3d227e0'Label'.leading == UITableViewCellContentView:0x7fd3f3d226f0.leadingMargin + 30>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fd3f53b73b0 'fittingSizeHTarget' H:[UITableViewCellContentView:0x7fd3f3d226f0(38)]>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fd3f3d23390 UITableViewCellContentView:0x7fd3f3d226f0.trailingMargin == UILabel:0x7fd3f3d227e0'Label'.trailing + 30>
```

I don't understand why adding an indicator would cause such a problem, it's nothing to do with the scale of the numbers, I've experimented quite a bit.

Any ideas?

The real world example a cell that has a label (the label) and then either another label or a text view that contains a value that can be set by following the disclosure. So the first label is a fixed size, the second ideally needs to be the max that it can be, but truncate the text if needed.

(See the 'ringtone' or 'vibration setting' within adding a contact for an example of what I'm trying to achieve)

Many thanks,

Lee.

Comment: I'm seeing the same problem. Everything seems to work fine, but the warning is there. If I remove the disclosure indicator, all works fine. Had any luck with this?

Comment: I had this same issue, and although I wasn't able to resolve this using storyboards, but by defining my UITableViewCell subclass's layout constraints in code I can get accessoryType's working!

Answer (score 55):

I just had the same problem. I want to layout an image-view on the left hand with a label on its right which fills the space between the image-view and the right (or trailing) border of superview (which is the cell's content-view). Accessory view is set to disclosure indicator as well.
As in your case the conflicting constraints where all H-based and one I found in the logs where `fittingSizeHTarget`. I didn't found out what this means nor where this was coming from, but I found your post here.

The following did the trick for me:

**Lower the priority of your label's trailing-to-superview constraint. (I chose 990).**

I assume, that the layout system (with the disclosure indicator visible) for what ever reason can't satisfy all the constraints anymore, so it breaks one. But if you lower the priority, it still tries to satisfy the constraint, but doesn't break it as the conflicting constraint(s) have higher priority.

Hope this solves your problem as well.

Comment: worked for me thanks - decluttered the log output in Xcode :)

Comment: Wracked my brain on this far longer than I should've. This solution worked for me as well. Seems like something the frameworks should be doing on their own since the disclosure indicator and all are just stock UIKit items.

Comment: Lower the priority of label's trailing, it works for me

Comment: Nice catch @dergab, thanks! For the record, 990 didn't do it for me, so I tried 1, which resulted in the text of the label overflowing below the disclosure indicator o_O. *500* did the trick.

Comment: just a note. It seems that fittingSizeHTarget is : self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 89
self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension in other words, the property to make the uitableviewcell fit his content...

Comment: @Dragouf: It seems to me, that the issue is a "horizontal" one. As for the name fittingSizeHTarget and the way it can be solved (lowering a horizontal constraint's priority). Therefore I would assume that "rowHeight" doesn't influence here. ;)

Comment: RowHeight no but automaticDimenssion yes. Anyway I found same solution as you. Lowered the priority of the right constraint solve the problem. But what is the explanation ?

Comment: I could not get the trailing-to-superview constraint to work when lowering the priority. The label extended behind the accessory. Eventually, I got rid of the warning by lowering the priority of the image width to 999. The image still retained it desired width.

Comment: Weird thing. I just stumbled across breaking autolayout constraints log messages involving a `fittingSizeHTarget`, which I have never added via IB. Luckily I've found this SO question and answer. What's strange is, that reducing the priority to High (= 750) leads to overlapping label and disclosure indicating whereas setting the priority to 751 fixes the problem.

Comment: This is a really strange one. Lowering the priority of the right-hand constraint stopped the "breaking constraint..." warnings for me, but I'm still getting the "Zero height" warning like the OP.

Comment: Lowering the constraint's priority will suppress the warning, but so would deleting the constraint (hint: they do the same thing).  This is not a good answer: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AppKit/Reference/NSLayoutConstraint_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/NSLayoutConstraint/priority "All priorities less than 1,000 are optional."

Comment: @StephenGroom: You may want to read the docu you cite more carefully.
"Higher priority constraints are met before lower priority constraints.

Constraint satisfaction is not all or nothing. If a constraint a == b is optional, the constraint-based layout system will attempt to minimize abs(a-b)."
The layout system will try to satisfy the constraint as much as possible. Often, when the layout system breaks a constraint (`Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.`-error) the layout breaks all together. But lowering the priority of the right constraint will often "achieve" the desired layout.

Comment: In this instance though all it will do is break the constraint that is breaking anyway.  You are suppressing the error by telling it that it is ok to break the constraint if it can't satisfy everything.  If this is the correct outcome then you don't need the constraint at all

Comment: As it's your word against Apple's, until further notice, I stick with Apple's version. As the Apple-docs states, there are shades between _satisfy everything_ and _satisfy nothing_. With the constraint, the layout system (in example above) at least tries to get the trailing edge as near as 30pt to the edge of the superview. So for example, the trailing edges might be 70pt apart without the constraint in question. But maybe the layout system achieves 42pt with the constraint in question (added with lower priority) without conflicting with the rest of the (higher prioritized) constraints.

Answer (score 2):

Please pay attention to what Stephen says in the comment section of the **upvoted answer**. The upvoted answer is **somewhat correct**, but it's important to understand why it should only be used in certain scenarios.

Priorities are usually used in context where element A has a constraint saying height is equal or less/more than 300, and element B has one says height is equal or less/more than 500. Then autolayout can satisfy both conditions based on their priorities.

In this particular example, both constraints are set to specific value and lowering priority essentially tells to ignore that constraint if it's impossible to satisfy (there's no "partially ignore it"). **However** UILabel has an exception - default UILabel behaviour is to resize itself to fit the content unless it's constrained by additional margins (autosize constraint hides under fittingSizeHTarget name) and this behaviour sometimes shows false warnings. In reality this constraint will be ignored in the runtime, but before it becomes disabled internally it will file a warning. Therefore, even though we tell to ignore one of our constraints by lowering its priority (the one we set priority to 900), since autosize constraint will be ignored in runtime, our 900 priority will be applied and satisfied.

Comment: I hear everyone saying that this method (lowering the priority of your own constraint) is not recommended, however, **I have yet to hear a better alternative**. Complementing auto-layout with your own constraints will almost always yield conflicts since auto-layout tends to create required constraints (priority = 1000). **What is the alternative?**

Answer (score 2):

Raimunda's answer above explaining about the intrinsic size that happens on labels, buttons, etc being where this fittingSizeHTarget log is coming from was spot on. While you can leave it and let the system deal with it, it's a risky hack, because you're relying on the system to break an unwanted constraint...which it may not do in future releases. And in some cases, as in a view example I recently dealt with, lowering the priority of the trailing constraint to the outside safe area didn't prevent the label from overrunning (it did, however, fix the log warning lol).

For content issues like this, use the **Content Hugging Priority** and **Content Compression Resistance Priority** values. If you know that your label, for example, will want to increase in vertical height but constrain to a horizontal value, then make the vertical content hugging priority (Content hugging = the view resisting being made bigger) lower than the horizontal.

The Compression resistance is the opposite of this.

Then set your outside trailing constraint to a greater than or equal and you're good to go.

In the stack view below, the label titled Fake 4 actually overran and wanted to become two lines. That caused a conflict involving fittingSizeHTarget (the intrinsic content size wanted to stay on one line and overrun the view width). The key here was lowering the Horizontal Compression Resistance priority to lower than ALL of the other content priorities. This allowed me to lower the priority of the >= constraint on the trailing value, and everything behaves as expected.

Anyway, tweaking this stuff is annoying as heck, but those Hugging/Compression values, combined with some form of >= / <= are usually the answer.

Hope this helps.

[image]

Comment: I believe if you want the label width to be constant, you could leave the hugging and compression priorities alone. Instead you could set your trailing space to "=" instead of ">=" but lower the priority below 1000 like you did. iOS should adjust the trailing space as much as possible to match your constraint if it can't satisfy it completely.

Comment: @AndrewKirna ?? Did I imply the label width to be constant? I believe the problem here is one of overrunning. It needs to adjust dynamically to screen width and intrinsic content...and that's precisely why it can't be a constant width. And the OP question is about providing the AL engine enough info so it doesn't need to break constraints to do its job. In any case, getting a complicated layout to work right is never easy, so while your suggesting might work in some cases, in others, like mine, it probably didn't. Which is why I had to adjust priority.

Comment: Ok. I was just noting for future readers that you don’t have to sacrifice a constant label width in order to satisfy AL. After all, the OP did request that the label “largely **fill** the space.”

Comment: It's not about "sacrifice" lol The choice between using constants, >=, priorities and all the tools is about context. Which, in some cases requires adjusting priorities. That is, after all, why Apple has exposed them to us. And note that FILL the space does not mean a constant label width. There are, as I'm sure you are aware, screens of varying widths...so your labels probably should NEVER be a constant width if they are designed to fill a wide screen and then adjust to a narrower screen. It's all about context.

Comment: I meant to say you don’t have to sacrifice a *uniform* label width (that is, among reusable cell instances). I agree that you shouldn’t use constant sizes for items that need to adapt to the device size. Note…I also agreed with you in my first comment that adjusting priorities is beneficial.