# iOS 8 Custom Self Sizing Table View : Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, ios8

In `UITableViewController`, I am using custom `UITableView` cell. This cell contains a `UIImage` control on left side of cell and two `UILabels`(one is for product name and other is for product description, which can be varying length) to the right of this `UIImage`. I have added Auto Layout constraints on all three controls. There is no issue in Auto Layout control. However when I run the app, I get the following error messages (one for each row in the table) and a couple of top rows are not as per auto layout constraints, but however when I scroll down and then scroll up, everything is rendered as per the auto layout constraints

```
Debug Log:
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
- Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.     
Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
Try this: 
(1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
(2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints) 
 (
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x170085ff0 H:[PFImageView:0x14ee1d350(60)]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x17408a500 PFImageView:0x14ee1d350.leading == UITableViewCellContentView:0x14ee1cdf0.leadingMargin + 7>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x17408a5a0 UITableViewCellContentView:0x14ee1cdf0.trailingMargin == UILabel:0x14ed08580'Naturally Sandstone Slabs'.trailing + 10>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x17408a5f0 H:[PFImageView:0x14ee1d350]-(11)-[UILabel:0x14ed08580'Naturally Sandstone Slabs']>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x17008c6c0 'fittingSizeHTarget' H:[UITableViewCellContentView:0x14ee1cdf0(34)]>" )

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint  <NSLayoutConstraint:0x170085ff0 H:[PFImageView:0x14ee1d350(60)]>

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger. The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKit/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue was because i was using a disclosure indicator in the table view. Lowering the priority of label's trailing-to-superview constraint. (I chose 990) fixed the issue.

Below is the link where i get the solution:

[ios8 cell constraints break when adding disclosure indicator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26652854/ios8-cell-constraints-break-when-adding-disclosure-indicator)