# Autolayout Error With Simple Custom UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitableview, autolayout

Here is my layout:

[image]

The question is about second custom cell. I have one UIImageView and one UILabel. I want to have an image aligned at the left side of cell and label filled the other free space.

**I've recorded a GIF animation to show you the process**:

[image]

The result is OK. But then I want to select the Detail Accessory option for my custom cell.

After that I get this:

```
2016-09-21 11:23:57.976 ODFileManager2[4861:70193] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. Try this: (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints) 
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fe62addd190 H:[fileIcon(43)]   (Names: fileIcon:0x7fe62addcfc0 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fe62addf1b0 fileIcon.leading == UITableViewCellContentView:0x7fe62addc2c0.leadingMargin   (Names: fileIcon:0x7fe62addcfc0 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fe62addf340 H:[fileIcon]-(0)-[UILabel:0x7fe62addc7d0'Label']   (Names: fileIcon:0x7fe62addcfc0 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fe62addf390 UITableViewCellContentView:0x7fe62addc2c0.trailingMargin == UILabel:0x7fe62addc7d0'Label'.trailing>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fe62ade5e20 'fittingSizeHTarget' H:[UITableViewCellContentView:0x7fe62addc2c0(48)]>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fe62addd190 H:[fileIcon(43)]   (Names: fileIcon:0x7fe62addcfc0 )>

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKit/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
```

Although everything still looks good.

Comment: Have you try add the constraint after put the cell's accessory there?

Comment: I agree with @Tj3n, but there must be some explanation behind this warning.

Comment: are you increasing the height of cell dynamically?

Comment: You may have added a constraint that you may don't need. This means, removing a constraint will not effect your view and will satisfy all the devices.

Comment: @Tj3n, Yes and there is no difference.

Comment: @Mr.UB, I do not change the height of cell in the code. But I do want cell changing it's height dynamically according to the intrinsic size. In this case cell's height supposed to be equal to image height

Comment: OK, I think the warning is because the accessory view you added, check this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26652854/ios8-cell-constraints-break-when-adding-disclosure-indicator), this guy had the same problem, and resolved it by lowering the priority of Label's trailing constraint

Comment: @EricQian, thanks a lot. This really works, but it still quite weird. Also, I had another solution: apply right trailing constraint not to the margin but to the superview's edge itself. But after a couple of times of doing it I can't repeat it again o_o

Answer (score 1):

There is some issue with height, you set it 43, but cell height is 48.

One get around with this issue is:

1. Remove Constraint: Bottom and top constraint of `fileIcon`.
2. Add Constraint: Center Vertically in container

Comment: In that case there is an ambiguity: the image can be centered vertically and has leading padding with many different heights of parent container. So cell's height becomes equal to label height. It's wrong. And I get fileIcon bigger than cell's height. Cell's height must depend of image's top and bottom edges. And label must fill the remaining space.

Comment: You mean to say that the height of the cell will increase with the Size of the Image.

Answer (score 0):

Just chekced your gif, you pined `fileIcon`'s top and bottom to cell's top and bottom, and then you set the `fileIcon`'s height constraint to 43, but the cell's height is 48 according to the warning message. That's why autolayout cannot fulfill the constraints.

Comment: I dont know why cell's height is 48. I want cell changing it's height dynamically according to intrinsic size.  Actually at IB the Row Height is 87 but at Runtime it has no influence.

Comment: Remove `fileIcon`'s top and bottom constraints, instead align it center vertically in cell. Then pin `Label`'s top and bottom to cell's top and bottom with a proper padding space. After that you need to set tableView's `estimatedRowHeight` to some resonable value. At last retrun `UITableViewAutomaticDimension` in `tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:`

Comment: In that case there is an ambiguity: the image can be centered vertically and has leading padding with many different heights of parent container. And I get fileIcon bigger than cell's height. Cell's height must depend of image's top and bottom edges. And label must fill the remaining space. UITableViewAutomaticDimension and estimatedRowHeight are set.

Comment: Then the cell's height is static, cause the `fileIcon`'s height is static

Answer (score 0):

First you should update the frames of constraints after you set/change any constraint, but you have not done that as shown in the GIF you provided.

To answer your issue, what you are doing wrong here is you are setting fixed points constraint that you should not do. Follow below steps and you will get rid of all warnings,

1. Set Leading Space, Centre Vertically, Fixed Height and Fixed Width constraint to the imageView.

[image]

2. Set Labels Leading Space constraint to the imageView and set Top Space, Trailing Space and Bottom Space to SuperView with Standard Spacing that is it should not be fixed points.

[image]

So this way your image will be fixed in size and you label can increase in height and width as per the text size.

[image]

After doing this if needed (If constraint are showing in orange color) update the frames.

Hope this helps you to understand the rules of Auto layout..

Good Luck...